# Opencart Installation and Display Errors

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I need a bit of help installing a copy of Opencart onto my Godaddy hosting. I have had one major problem and that was, after during and after the install, none of the styles or images where appearing. I was able to completely fix the admin panel, but I am now running into problems with the frontend. I was able to fix the styles by editing a couple lines in the index.php file:

```
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/opencart/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://jpoles1.com/image/');
```

Now the problem is that unless you are on the base url http://jpoles1.com/opencart/, none of the database functionality works. For example the brands dropdown on the left will only be populated on the root page.

Am I going about this problem the wrong way?
What should I do to fix this problem?

--

Thanks,
Jordan

Answer (score 0):

> define('HTTP_IMAGE',
>   'http://jpoles1.com/image/')

Should be

> define('HTTP_IMAGE',
>   'http://jpoles1.com/opencart/image/')

try it

Answer (score 0):

```
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '.........');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '........');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '.........');
```

are you replace setting?

Comment: This seems like a comment not an answer

Answer (score 0):

got Notice: Use of undefined constant HTTP_IMAGE